# $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n $For what values does $x$ converge? Diverge? Justify.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

For what values of $x$ does this converge? Diverge? And show justification
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n $$
I know that it converges when $|x| < 1$ and diverges when $|x| \ge 1$

However I don't know how to justify this. I can explain it by writing and I did it so by saying this

> If you raise a number greater or equal to 1 to a power and add each value, it would go to infinity. However if you take a fraction and raise it to a power, the denominator gets larger and faster, than the numerator, meaning the last term will be $0$ and there will be a final term, meaning there will be a number of finite terms, rather than a number of infinite terms meaning it converges.

I think this is correct, however I'm not so sure how to justify this with "math"

Comment: The divergence for $|x| \geq 1$ can also be deduced from the $n$-th term test because the series converges only if $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^n = 0$. (But this is not enough to show convergence when $|x| \lt 1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Recall that for $x\ne 1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^N x^n=\frac{x-x^{N+1}}{1-x}$$

Comment: I just got to that point right now! I substracted the two equations I created (the original one, and the one where i multiplied r into it) but now I'm unsure what to do from there

Comment: $S_N=1+x+\cdots x^N$, $xS_N=S_N+(x^{N+1}-1)$.  Can you finish now?

Comment: [I did it, but this is where I ended up](https://i.gyazo.com/14e8626e00a9474d1d3fd21000ecd0e2.png)

Comment: You have $S_N=\frac{x-x^{N+1}}{1-x}$.  As $N\to \infty$, $S_N\to \frac{x}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$ and diverges for $|x|\ge 1$, which is evident by examining $\lim_{N\to \infty}x^{N+1}$.

Comment: This makes so much sense now, thank you so much!

Comment: Pleased to hear. And you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

One can also use the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test) to show absolute convergence: 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a^{n+1}}{a^n} \right| < 1 $$

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n} \right| = \lim_{n\to\infty}|x| =  |x| < 1 $$

Comment: I'm a bit worried this might be circular. Proofs of the ratio test usually involve bounding $\sum |a_n|$ by a convergent geometric series.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I believe the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1164166/274085) avoid referencing convergent geometrics using an $\epsilon$ proof.