# Confusion about $\limsup$ properties in proof of ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

In the proof of the ratio test in my notes, which is similar to the one [here](https://mathcs.org/analysis/reals/numser/t_ratio.html), the first step revolves around an obvious statement which is not proved. However, for whatever reason, I can't make out why it is at all obvious!

Note for our case, $a_n\geq0$ for all $n$. The comment in question is that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$$ implies that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1-\epsilon$$ for all $n\geq N$, for some $N$.

I have also seen this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164138/ratio-test-with-limsup-vs-lim) which seems to have include the same comment, but it doesn't seem to explain it in detail.

I can't figure out why this is true, but I suspect it is obvious, so any guidance would be much appreciated!

**Edit:** Our definition of $\limsup$ is $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sup_{n\geq N} a_n$, or that it is the maximal limit point of $a_n$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\limsup$?

Comment: @Dude Clarified in edit

Comment: Yes. So assume on the contrary that your inequality does not hold. Is it true that $\lim sup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$? No because that means that an infinite number of those ratios is getting close to something greater than or equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be argued very closely from definitions, although it's just making rigorous the intuitive notion that the ratios must maintain *some* distance from $1$, as otherwise they would tend to at least $1$, making their $\limsup$ at least $1$.

Let $\ell = \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_{n + 1}/a_n$. We are given that $\ell < 1$, so certainly $\tfrac 12(1 - \ell) > 0$.

Since $\ell = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sup_{n \ge m} a_{n + 1}/a_n$, by the definition of the limit of a sequence (letting $\varepsilon = \tfrac 12(1 - \ell)$), we can find some $N$ such that for all $m \ge N$, $\sup_{n \ge m} a_{n + 1}/a_n - \ell < \tfrac 12(1 - \ell)$. (Here I have omitted the modulus as the sequence $(\sup_{n \ge m} a_{n + 1}/a_n)$ is decreasing as a sequence in $m$, so $\ell \le \sup_{n \ge m} a_{n + 1}/a_n$).

Particularly, taking $m = N$, we get $\sup_{n \ge N} a_{n + 1}/a_n - \ell < \tfrac 12(1 - \ell)$.

But then, we have $\sup_{n \ge N} a_{n + 1}/a_n < \tfrac 12(1 + \ell) = 1 - \tfrac 12(1 - \ell)$. Since $\sup$ is an upper bound, for *any* $k \ge N$, we get $a_{k + 1}/a_k \le \sup_{n \ge N} a_{n + 1}/a_n < 1 - \tfrac 12(1 - \ell)$.

So $N$ is our $N$, and our $\varepsilon$ is $\tfrac 12(1 - \ell)$.

You might notice that this is actually a general fact about $\limsup$ of a sequence with a strict upper bound. We didn't need to use positivity of $a_n$ for this step of the proof.

Comment: Can one think of it this way? $\sup a_{n+1}/a_n < 1+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, so we know that $\sup a_{n+1}/a_n < 1$ and hence $a_{n+1}/a_n < 1$, so this ratio must be less than or equal to $1-\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @Benjamin, I don't follow exactly what you're saying. Do you mean $\limsup$? I don't see what the $1 + \varepsilon$ is doing. $x < 1 + \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ doesn't imply that $x < 1$. It also seems like at the end you show that $a_{n + 1} / a_n < 1 - \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon$, but in your question you need to show that the same epsilon works for all $n$. Perhaps that's what you're arguing but it would be made clearer by saying something like "for all $n$".

Comment: You're right, of course, this was a silly argument. I follow your proof, but I don't see what's quite so 'obvious' about it. I'm trying to also understand why the statement is 'morally right', so to speak.

Comment: @Benjamin, The way I think of it is that the $\limsup$ of a sequence is a sort of "eventual upper bound". After a while, the sequence *must* quieten down and stay below any number above the $\limsup$. All this argument says is "if the eventual upper bound is *strictly* less than $1$, then we can pull the sequence down below $1$". Certainly if this claim were not true, then the sequence would be at least $1$ infinitely often, so it wouldn't make any sense for the eventual upper bound to be less than $1$. Maybe that helps. If not, don't worry. Analysis can be hard to build intuition about.

Comment: This does help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

let us call the $limsup$ as $p$, now $p<1$ , define $e =(1-p)/2$ so $ 1>1 - e>p$ , if all point after some certain $n$ didn't lie below $1-e$, (let us call $1-e$ as $\beta$), we can find infinitely many point of the seq which lies above $\beta$ (why?).   we can always create a subseq which converges to a number (in the extended reals) $\alpha$ greater than or equal $\beta$ .So it is a limit of a subseq greater than the limsup, which is a contradiction!